# Dynamic positioning (bottom or right) of card in vuejs or javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add a card to the container, then once the 1st card is created there are 2 buttons on the box located on the right and bottom, once the user clicks the button on the right it will add a box on the right side, same once click the button on the bottom it will create a box at the bottom. The card dimensions (width, height, space between right and bottom) are dynamic. I want to do this on Vuejs.

Here is the example UI that I want to create:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D4G7.png)
[and Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojOBJ.png)

[https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-pasteur-wy1iy](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-pasteur-wy1iy?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: You can use either an old-school table or the new CSS grid.

Comment: I think grid CSS will not work on this because of the dynamic positioning and dynamic width and height, and I'm not sure how to apply grid on this?

Comment: Well, then you can try with `position:absolute` and position your cards dynamically.

Comment: How can I make the card position dynamic? I tried using getBoundingClientRect but the top and left result is not exact.

Comment: The values for the bounding rect are relative to the top left corner of the screen - not to the top left of the HTML document. If the position is dynamic (as you claim) - then you (your code) need to compute the coordinates of each card. If you want an automatic layout like the photos in Flickr - then you can take a look at https://github.com/flickr/justified-layout or https://muuri.dev/

Comment: I check this component it helps me on displaying the card, but my problem is getting the current card position. I can't get the exact top and left position?

Comment: Position is always relative to something - either to the screen or to the parent DOM element. The bounding rect is relative to screen. `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` in combination with `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` may give you some hints.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, It's help me a lot to fixed the positioning of the box.